# How to set Currency by default Billing Address Country in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, currency, billing-address, default

In my setup only logged in customers can see prices and order. **How to set currency due to their default billing address?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can anybody help how the Observer at the customer login could look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no built in mapping between countries and currencies, you have to do this on your own.

For setting current currency depending on customers billing address you can add an observer for `customer_login` event with this code:

```
public function setStoreCurrency(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $mapping = array (
        {country_code} => {currency_code},
        ...
    );

    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $countryCode = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountry();
    if (isset($mapping[$countryCode]) && !is_null($mapping[$countryCode])) {
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($mapping[$countryCode]);
    }
}
```

Further steps:

- enable currencies from system config - *(General -> Currency Setup -> Allowed Currencies)*
- set exchange rate - *(System -> Mangage Currency -> Rates)*

Notes:

- changing storeview als changes currency to storeviews default one
- if customers billing address currency is not allowed, nothing happens

---

For currency mapping you **can** use this:

```
$mapping = array (
    'AC' => 'USD',
    'AD' => 'EUR',
    'AE' => 'AED',
    'AF' => 'AFN',
    'AG' => 'XCD',
    'AI' => NULL,
    'AL' => 'ALL',
    'AM' => 'AMD',
    'AN' => NULL,
    'AO' => 'AOA',
    'AQ' => NULL,
    'AR' => 'ARS',
    'AS' => 'USD',
    'AT' => 'EUR',
    'AU' => 'AUD',
    'AW' => 'AWG',
    'AX' => 'EUR',
    'AZ' => 'AZN',
    'BA' => 'BAM',
    'BB' => 'BBD',
    'BD' => 'BDT',
    'BE' => 'EUR',
    'BF' => 'XOF',
    'BG' => 'BGN',
    'BH' => 'BHD',
    'BI' => 'BIF',
    'BJ' => 'XOF',
    'BL' => 'EUR',
    'BM' => 'BMD',
    'BN' => 'BND',
    'BO' => 'BOB',
    'BQ' => NULL,
    'BR' => 'BRL',
    'BS' => 'BSD',
    'BT' => 'INR',
    'BU' => NULL,
    'BV' => 'NOK',
    'BW' => 'BWP',
    'BY' => NULL,
    'BZ' => 'BZD',
    'CA' => 'CAD',
    'CC' => 'AUD',
    'CD' => 'CDF',
    'CF' => 'XAF',
    'CG' => 'XAF',
    'CH' => 'CHF',
    'CI' => 'XOF',
    'CK' => 'NZD',
    'CL' => 'CLP',
    'CM' => 'XAF',
    'CN' => 'CNY',
    'CO' => 'COP',
    'CP' => 'EUR',
    'CR' => 'CRC',
    'CS' => NULL,
    'CT' => NULL,
    'CU' => 'CUP',
    'CV' => 'CVE',
    'CW' => 'ANG',
    'CX' => 'AUD',
    'CY' => 'EUR',
    'CZ' => 'CZK',
    'DD' => NULL,
    'DE' => 'EUR',
    'DG' => 'USD',
    'DJ' => 'DJF',
    'DK' => 'DKK',
    'DM' => 'XCD',
    'DO' => 'DOP',
    'DY' => NULL,
    'DZ' => 'DZD',
    'EA' => 'EUR',
    'EC' => 'USD',
    'EE' => 'EUR',
    'EG' => 'EGP',
    'EH' => 'MAD',
    'ER' => 'ERN',
    'ES' => 'EUR',
    'ET' => 'ETB',
    'EU' => 'EUR',
    'FI' => 'EUR',
    'FJ' => 'FJD',
    'FK' => 'FKP',
    'FM' => 'USD',
    'FO' => 'DKK',
    'FQ' => NULL,
    'FR' => 'EUR',
    'FX' => 'EUR',
    'GA' => 'XAF',
    'GB' => 'GBP',
    'GD' => 'XCD',
    'GE' => NULL,
    'GF' => 'EUR',
    'GG' => 'GBP',
    'GH' => 'GHS',
    'GI' => 'GIP',
    'GL' => 'DKK',
    'GM' => 'GMD',
    'GN' => 'GNF',
    'GP' => 'EUR',
    'GQ' => 'XAF',
    'GR' => 'EUR',
    'GS' => 'GBP',
    'GT' => 'GTQ',
    'GU' => 'USD',
    'GW' => 'XOF',
    'GY' => 'GYD',
    'HK' => 'HKD',
    'HM' => 'AUD',
    'HN' => 'HNL',
    'HR' => 'HRK',
    'HT' => 'HTG',
    'HU' => 'HUF',
    'HV' => NULL,
    'IC' => 'EUR',
    'ID' => 'IDR',
    'IE' => 'EUR',
    'IL' => 'ILS',
    'IM' => 'GBP',
    'IN' => 'INR',
    'IO' => 'USD',
    'IQ' => 'IQD',
    'IR' => 'IRR',
    'IS' => 'ISK',
    'IT' => 'EUR',
    'JE' => 'GBP',
    'JM' => 'JMD',
    'JO' => 'JOD',
    'JP' => 'JPY',
    'JT' => NULL,
    'KE' => 'KES',
    'KG' => 'KGS',
    'KH' => 'KHR',
    'KI' => 'AUD',
    'KM' => 'KMF',
    'KN' => 'XCD',
    'KP' => 'KPW',
    'KR' => 'KRW',
    'KW' => 'KWD',
    'KY' => 'KYD',
    'KZ' => 'KZT',
    'LA' => 'LAK',
    'LB' => 'LBP',
    'LC' => 'XCD',
    'LI' => 'CHF',
    'LK' => 'LKR',
    'LR' => 'LRD',
    'LS' => 'LSL',
    'LT' => 'EUR',
    'LU' => 'EUR',
    'LV' => 'EUR',
    'LY' => 'LYD',
    'MA' => 'MAD',
    'MC' => 'EUR',
    'MD' => 'MDL',
    'ME' => 'EUR',
    'MF' => 'EUR',
    'MG' => 'MGA',
    'MH' => 'USD',
    'MI' => NULL,
    'MK' => 'MKD',
    'ML' => 'XOF',
    'MM' => 'MMK',
    'MN' => 'MNT',
    'MO' => 'MOP',
    'MP' => 'USD',
    'MQ' => 'EUR',
    'MR' => 'MRO',
    'MS' => 'XCD',
    'MT' => 'EUR',
    'MU' => 'MUR',
    'MV' => 'MVR',
    'MW' => 'MWK',
    'MX' => 'MXN',
    'MY' => 'MYR',
    'MZ' => 'MZN',
    'NA' => 'NAD',
    'NC' => 'XPF',
    'NE' => 'XOF',
    'NF' => 'AUD',
    'NG' => 'NGN',
    'NH' => NULL,
    'NI' => 'NIO',
    'NL' => 'EUR',
    'NO' => 'NOK',
    'NP' => 'NPR',
    'NQ' => NULL,
    'NR' => 'AUD',
    'NT' => NULL,
    'NU' => 'NZD',
    'NZ' => 'NZD',
    'OM' => 'OMR',
    'PA' => 'PAB',
    'PC' => NULL,
    'PE' => 'PEN',
    'PF' => 'XPF',
    'PG' => 'PGK',
    'PH' => 'PHP',
    'PK' => 'PKR',
    'PL' => 'PLN',
    'PM' => 'EUR',
    'PN' => 'NZD',
    'PR' => 'USD',
    'PS' => 'JOD',
    'PT' => 'EUR',
    'PU' => NULL,
    'PW' => 'USD',
    'PY' => 'PYG',
    'PZ' => NULL,
    'QA' => 'QAR',
    'RE' => 'EUR',
    'RH' => NULL,
    'RO' => 'RON',
    'RS' => 'RSD',
    'RU' => 'RUB',
    'RW' => 'RWF',
    'SA' => 'SAR',
    'SB' => 'SBD',
    'SC' => 'SCR',
    'SD' => 'SDG',
    'SE' => 'SEK',
    'SG' => 'SGD',
    'SH' => 'SHP',
    'SI' => 'EUR',
    'SJ' => 'NOK',
    'SK' => NULL,
    'SL' => 'SLL',
    'SM' => 'EUR',
    'SN' => 'XOF',
    'SO' => 'SOS',
    'SR' => 'SRD',
    'SS' => 'SSP',
    'ST' => 'STD',
    'SU' => 'RUB',
    'SV' => 'USD',
    'SX' => 'ANG',
    'SY' => 'SYP',
    'SZ' => 'SZL',
    'TA' => 'GBP',
    'TC' => 'USD',
    'TD' => 'XAF',
    'TF' => 'EUR',
    'TG' => 'XOF',
    'TH' => 'THB',
    'TJ' => 'TJS',
    'TK' => 'NZD',
    'TL' => 'USD',
    'TM' => 'TMT',
    'TN' => 'TND',
    'TO' => 'TOP',
    'TP' => NULL,
    'TR' => 'TRY',
    'TT' => 'TTD',
    'TV' => 'AUD',
    'TW' => 'TWD',
    'TZ' => 'TZS',
    'UA' => 'UAH',
    'UG' => 'UGX',
    'UK' => 'GBP',
    'UM' => 'USD',
    'US' => 'USD',
    'UY' => 'UYU',
    'UZ' => 'UZS',
    'VA' => 'EUR',
    'VC' => 'XCD',
    'VD' => NULL,
    'VE' => 'VEF',
    'VG' => 'USD',
    'VI' => 'USD',
    'VN' => 'VND',
    'VU' => 'VUV',
    'WF' => 'XPF',
    'WK' => NULL,
    'WS' => 'WST',
    'XK' => 'EUR',
    'YD' => NULL,
    'YE' => 'YER',
    'YT' => 'EUR',
    'YU' => NULL,
    'ZA' => 'ZAR',
    'ZM' => 'ZMW',
    'ZR' => NULL,
    'ZW' => 'USD',
);
```

**Note:** i can not guarantee that data is correct - it's just grabbed from [`OpenBookPrices/country-data`](https://github.com/OpenBookPrices/country-data/blob/master/data/countries.json)!

Comment: It still does not switch to PLN when my customers default billing address is in Poland.Any clue?
 
 
 `public function setStoreCurrency(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $mapping = array();
        $mapping['DE'] = 'EUR';
        $mapping['PL'] = 'PLN';

        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $countryCode = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountry();
        if (isset($mapping[$countryCode]) && !is_null($mapping[$countryCode])) {
            Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($mapping[$countryCode]);
        }
    }`

Comment: Have you enabled PLN as allowed currency and set a exchange rate?

Comment: Country and Currency are allowed and rates set but it always shows EUR with my prices. I can only switch them with the currency switcher.

Comment: Does it work in your store?

Comment: @SelfDiagnostics Yes, it does. Can you please check customer address? Have tested it (even with PLN). Before login it set is to EUR, after login currency changed to PLN. Its important to set currency exchange rate in "admin - system - manage currency - rates"!

Comment: @SelfDiagnostics can you please test it with other currencies?

Comment: I will test it as soon as possible but probably not anymore today.

Comment: I have another problem what I have to solve first, I will come back to the issue as soon as possible

Comment: The code works, the problem was my store. Thank you!

Comment: @SelfDiagnostics You're welcome :) Please upvote too if it solved your problem. Btw ... can do same with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184711/get-customer-billing-address-country-short-code-iso-code since it uses same code. Regards.