# Get customer billing address country short code (ISO Code)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, billing-address, countries

How can I get the country short code (ISO) of the billing address of a logged in customer. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: @sv3N Not yet, unfortunately. My observer is observing is basically working now, thanks to your help on the other issue [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186340/observer-problem-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/186344#186344). My final goal is to display the right currency to a logged in customer (B2B Shop). The currency refers to the default billing address country and its official currency. That does not work yet. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: I've read your other question ... I'm setting up a new multistore system at the moment, so I'll require this too. Guess it will take one or two days, to get a solution - have to finish other stuff first.

Comment: Feel free to share your findings ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    $countryCode = $session->getCustomer()->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountry();
}
```

Comment: How to get full country name instead of a country code, here is my code return only country code: https://www.pastiebin.com/5ce2558df3370 @sv3n

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$customerAddress->getCountryModel()->getName()
```